# Strange issue when using google DFP API python client

Tags: python, if-statement, try-catch

have a look at this code

```
order_service = client.GetService('OrderService', version='v201208')
creative_service = client.GetService('CreativeService', version='v201208')
with open('/tmp/urls.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in range(0, 3929, 100):
        print 'ORDER BY ID LIMIT 100 OFFSET '+str(i)
        creatives = creative_service.getCreativesByStatement({'query':'ORDER BY ID LIMIT 100 OFFSET '+str(i)})
        try:
            for creative in creatives[0]['results']:
                try:
                    for var in creative['creativeTemplateVariableValues']:
                        if var['uniqueName'] == 'DetailsPageURL':                           
                            print var['value']
                            f.write(creative['advertiserId']+','+var['value']+"\n")
                exception:
                    pass
        except:
            raise
            pass
```

The second iteration when offset is 200, will complain at `for creative in creatives[0]['results']` about results keyerror, but if I change a try/except statement to `if creative.has_key('creativeTemplateVariableValues'):` like following fixes the problem:

```
order_service = client.GetService('OrderService', version='v201208')
creative_service = client.GetService('CreativeService', version='v201208')
with open('/tmp/urls.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in range(0, 3929, 100):
        print 'ORDER BY ID LIMIT 100 OFFSET '+str(i)
        creatives = creative_service.getCreativesByStatement({'query':'ORDER BY ID LIMIT 100 OFFSET '+str(i)})
        try:
            print creatives[0]['results']
        except:
            print creatives
        #creatives = creative_service.getCreativesByStatement({'query':'ORDER BY ID LIMIT 10 OFFSET 200'})
        try:
            for creative in creatives[0]['results']:
                if creative.has_key('creativeTemplateVariableValues'):
                    for var in creative['creativeTemplateVariableValues']:
                        if var['uniqueName'] == 'DetailsPageURL':
                            print var['value']
                            f.write(creative['advertiserId']+','+var['value']+"\n")
        except:
            raise
            pass
```

Why???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field 'creativeTemplateVariableValues' creatives of type 'TemplateCreative' so if you have other creatives on your network that's not a TemplateCreative, it will not have the field and throw the key error as you have seen. You can do the has_key check as you have done or an alternative is to do a type check:

```
if creative['Creative_Type'] == 'ImageCreative':
  for var in creative['creativeTemplateVariableValues']:
    ...
```

If you only care about TemplateCreatives, I would suggest using a statement filter for that particular creative type. Please see the get_creatives_by_statement example (http://code.google.com/p/google-api-ads-python/source/browse/trunk/examples/adspygoogle/dfp/v201208/get_creatives_by_statement.py)

For future questions regarding DFP API and the related client libraries, please post to the DFP API forum: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-doubleclick-for-publishers-api